# Extract the last directory by sftp

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sftp

I have a script that allows you to connect via sftp to a server and what I want is to go to a directory and bring the last directory created with all the subfolders and files, although the one I put here as an example is wrong and what it does is extract all the folders and does not put the file, what am I doing wrong? Thank you very much

```
#!/bin/bash 
HOST=192.168.1.133 
PORT=22 
USER=root 
PASSWORD=password 
SOURCE_FILE=/root/logs 
DIA=`date +"%d/%m/%Y"` 
HORA=`date +"%H:%M"` 
TIME=`$DAY+$HOUR` 
TARGET_DIR="ls -td -- */ | head -n 1" 
/usr/bin/expect<<EOD > output.log 
spawn /usr/bin/sftp -o Port=$PORT $USER@$HOST 
expect "password:" 
send "$PASSWORD\r" 
expect "sftp>" 
send "get -r $SOURCE_FILE $TIME $TARGET_DIR\r" 
expect "sftp>" 
send "bye\r" 
EOD 
RC=$? 
if [[ ${RC} -ne 0 ]]; then   
   cat output.log | mail
-s "Errors Received" "email@domain.com" 
else   
    echo "Success" | mail -s "Transfer Successful" "email@domain.com" 
fi
```

Comment: (1) The code in your question seems mangled. Please [edit] and fix it. (2) `sshfs` may be able to simplify things because it allows you to work with remote files as if they were local ([example](https://superuser.com/a/1315346/432690)).

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is a remote sftp server and I have no permissions on that server except to read the files or download them.

Comment: Your "but" sounds as if this setup prevented you from locally using `sshfs` and then `ls`, `find`, `cp` or whatever. I am not convinced there is anything that disallows this. Local limitations (e.g. no `sshfs` and no permissions to install/get it), yes, they could; but you were talking about the server. If you can `sftp` then probably `sshfs` will also work. I'm not saying you should switch from `sftp` to `sshfs`. My point is `sshfs` plus local standard tools often create a more elegant solution than `sftp` driven by `expect`.

Comment: I edit and format you code, line with `TARGET_DIR` is unlikely to do what you expect. (I don't have access to sftp client now, I'll be back)

Comment: Thank you very much for editing

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem, it is like this in case someone needs it, greetings.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=192.168.1.123

PORT=3355

USER=lab

PASSWORD=demo

DIR=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")

 

/usr/bin/expect<<EOD > output.log

spawn /usr/bin/sftp -o Port=$PORT $USER@$HOST

expect "password:"

send "$PASSWORD\r"

expect "sftp>"

send "cd logs\r"

expect "sftp>"

send "mget -r $DIR\r"

expect "sftp>"

send "bye\r"

EOD

RC=$?

 

#if [[ ${RC} -ne 0 ]]; then

#  cat output.log | mail -s "Errors Received" email@domain.com

#else

#  echo "Success" | mail -s "Transfer Successful" email@domain.com

#fi
```